# Runtime addition of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer bean

Tags: java, spring

In our web application design we need two spring context xml files. One will be loaded during deployment time and other one will be loaded programmatically at runtime.

**PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** beans are configured in both xml files. But it is working only for deployed spring xml. **PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer** bean defined in second xml file which is loaded at runtime is not taking effect on the properties defined inside that xml.

Sample **Spring.xml** which load's at deployment.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" id="Deployment_props">
<property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${APZ:"/>
<property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}"/>
<property name="location" value="classpath:Server/META-INF/Env.properties"/>
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>


<bean class="com.dao.HttpDetails" id="Admin_http" scope="request">
<property name="callType" value="POST"/>
<property name="timeOut" value="${APZ:timeout}"/>
</bean>
```

Sample **Spring-app.xml** which load's at runtime.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer" id="Runtime_props">
<property name="placeholderPrefix" value="${APZ:"/>
<property name="placeholderSuffix" value="}"/>
<property name="location" value="classpath:Admin/Env.properties"/>
<property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>


<bean class="com.dao.HttpDetails" id="Service_http" scope="request">
<property name="callType" value="POST"/>
<property name="timeOut" value="${APZ:time}"/>
</bean>
```

code used to load xml beans at runtime:

```
        WebApplicationContext context = Frameworks.getWebAppContext();
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        BeanDefinitionRegistry registry = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) factory;
        XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlReader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(registry);
        xmlReader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_XSD);

        try {
            xmlReader.loadBeanDefinitions(
                    new InputSource(AppIntialization.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Spring-app.xml")));
        } catch (BeanDefinitionStoreException e) {

        }
```

Everything defined in Spring-app.xml is working except for **PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer** bean.
Any suggestions or work around would be appreciated.

Comment: Why that contraption to load the files? Also why  2 different files? The difference should be in the properties not the whole loading and definition of beans? Looks like you are trying very hard to work around the framework instead of working with the framework.

Comment: @M.Deinum We are implementing multitenancy. So when a new tenant is added at rutime we will load all the bean xml's and property files related to that tenant without restarting application server. That second xml file is the configuration of new tenant.

Comment: You are actually replacing the beans not extending them. Also loading beans per tenant is generally a bad idea (you are basically loading the full application again for each tenant, which kind of beats the purpose of multi-tenancy).

Comment: I am not replacing beans. Every tenant has different beans ids and different bean definitions depending on the services they use. Our application is working fine except for using these propertyplaceholders

Comment: Still you are (re)loading parts you shouldn't be reloading (and which kind of beats the multitenancy purpose). You are only loading beans in a beanfactory NOT in an applicationcontext. So things like post processing of beans or bean-definitions for that matter simply won't work.